# EE 1.13.1 install samples data

Tags: magento-enterprise, ee-1.13, sample-data

New Magento EE has many changes (and bug as well ) in the URL rewrite/redirect part for this reason I'm quite sure `sample data` are not 100% compatible with this new release.

Are there any `sample data` compatible for 1.13 ? 
Assuming the answer to this question is 'no' I wonder if the below points are good.

Should I:

1. Install `sample data`
2. Install Magento
3. Run the migration script ?

Comment: yes...you should

Comment: unfortunately it is not working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above steps are not working, because:

- `migration script` is working only if `core_url_rewrite` is populated and Samples Data doesn't contains data for `core_url_rewrite` table.
- Re-indexing on 1.13.1 doesn't populate table `core_url_rewrite`.

So basically re-index will fix the links on frontend but backend view `catalog -> url redirect` will **be empty**.

The whole migration process to EE 1.13.1 described in [magento guideline](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee11302-ce18-install-upgrade#upgrade-manual-post-upgrade-11302) is far to be stable ( or better 1.13.1 is still bugged ) and at the moment there are not `samples data` for EE 1.13.1